# Is there a way to backup save files in Machinarium?

Tags: macos, machinarium

*Machinarium* (Mac OS X) saves its files in a cache, so if you accidentally clear your browsing history, all of your files disappear. Is there any way to back them up?

Comment: That question answered how to backup saved files on Windows, but not on the Mac OS X version. If you feel like it's still too similar to that question, though, go ahead and close this one.

Comment: @Dante Unless I'm mistaken, the accepted answer in the linked duplicate contains a Mac section.  Does that not help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Mac OS X you should find your savegame here:

```
~/Library/Preferences/Macromedia/Flash Player/#SharedObjects/{RANDOMWORD}/localhost/{PathToYourMachinariumInstallDirectory}/machinarium.app/Machinarium.sol
```

To do a backup you can physically copy the file and store it away.

Anyway to get more informations take a look at [this thread](http://amanita-design.net/forum/index.php?topic=463.0) on Amanita Design.

Answer (score 4):

Even better for you - the creator of the game has provided a tool to backup the saved game (great, for example, if you want to move from Steam to the direct download of the game without losing your save points).

The thread for it is here:

http://amanita-design.net/forum/index.php?topic=809.0

Simply download saves.exe and put it in the same folder as Machinarium.exe.  Choose option 1 and you're sorted!

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can type "Rebol" at the startscreen and pick a level to start from.